# Tune the coordinates of this arc

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphdrawing

I want to make a hyperbola that will host the points that have the same distance from two circles. Not really interested in accuracy, but in rather a figure that will give students the idea. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (2,2) circle (1cm);
    \draw (5,0) .. controls (6,4) and (5,6) .. (3,6);
    \draw (10,2) circle (3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{All points that are equidistant from both circles, lie on the hyperbola}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Can you please help?

[image]

Comment: ,@gsamaras --"The parabola is the locus of points that are equidistant from both the `directrix` and the`focus` in the plane containing both of them." This is one of the most common definitions of a parabola. So, how would you define it by circles?

Comment: I do not really care in defining it @AboAmmar, I just want a shape like the one I drew, but I would like the down curve to be similar to the one above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example scans the image area (part of it) line by line from bottom to top to find the *x* position, where the distances between the current point and the circles has the minimal difference. The distance from a point can be calculated by subtracting the radius from the distance of the current point to the center of the circle (and taking the absolute value for the case, the current point is inside the circle).

Calculations can be done with TikZ, but TeX does not provide fast calculations with real numbers, thus a different programming language would be better to speed the calculations up in this case of brute force calculations.

For example, a Perl script. Parameters are modified in the top area of the script. It output a list of points suitable for the `plot` drawing command.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($ax, $ay, $ar) = (2, 2, 1);
my ($bx, $by, $br) = (10, 2, 3);

my ($ymin, $ymax) = (-4, 8);
my ($xmin, $xmax) = ($ax, $bx);

my ($xstep, $ystep) = (.01, .01);

sub circledistance ($$$$$) {
    my ($radius, $mx, $my, $x, $y) = @_;
    my $xdiff = $mx - $x;
    my $ydiff = $my - $y;
    my $result = sqrt($xdiff * $xdiff + $ydiff * $ydiff) - $radius;
    $result = -$result if $result < 0;
    return $result;
}

sub round ($) {
    my $value = shift;
    return int($value + .5);
}

my $xcount = round(($xmax - $xmin)/$xstep);
my $ycount = round(($ymax - $ymin)/$ystep);

my @points;
for (my $yi = 0; $yi <= $ycount; $yi++) {
    my $diff = 1000000;
    my $point = '';
    my $y = $ymin + ($ymax - $ymin)*$yi/$ycount;
    for (my $xi = 0; $xi <= $xcount; $xi++) {
        my $x = $xmin + ($xmax - $xmin)*$xi/$xcount;
        my $a = circledistance($ar, $ax, $ay, $x, $y);
        my $b = circledistance($br, $bx, $by, $x, $y);
        my $d = $a - $b;
        $d = -$d if $d < 0;
        if ($d < $diff) {
            $diff = $d;
            $point = "($x,$y)";
        }
    }
    push @points, $point;
}

print "$_\n" foreach @points;

1;
__END__
```

Then the TeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\AX{2}
  \def\AY{2}
  \def\AR{1}
  \def\BX{10}
  \def\BY{2}
  \def\BR{3}
  \draw (\AX,\AY) circle (\AR cm);
  \draw (\BX,\BY) circle (\BR cm);
  \draw[red] plot[smooth] coordinates{
(4.16,-4)
(4.16,-3.99)
(4.16,-3.98)
(4.16,-3.97)
(4.16,-3.96)
(4.17,-3.95)
% ... <remaining lines of the output of the Perl script>
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{All points that are equidistant from both circles, lie on the
  hyperbola}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Oh, it's a beauty! I will search across the Stack network to find 2 answers of yours I like and upvote them too as a gift.

Answer (score 3):

A bit fragile (i.e., large numbers will break it) and doesn't take into account the angle between circles (so they are horizontal), but mostly it just involves a rearrangement of the cosine rule.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzmath{%
  integer \i, \j;
  \r = 2;
  \R = 6;
  \c = \r + 4 + \R;
  {
     \draw (0, 0) circle [radius=\r];
     \draw (\c, 0) circle [radius=\R];
  };
  for \i in {1,...,50}{
    \C = 180 - 100 + \i*4;
    \Z = (\c^2 - \r^2 - \R^2 + 2 * \r*\R) / (2 * (1 - cos(\C)));
    \q = (-(\r+\R) + sqrt((\r+\R)^2 - 4 * (\r*\R - \Z))) / 2;
    \a = \q + \r;
    \b = \q + \R;
    \B = asin(\b * sin(\C) / \c);  
    { \coordinate (n-\i) at (\B:\a); };
    if (\i > 1) then {
      \j = \i - 1;
      { \draw (n-\j) -- (n-\i); };
    };
  };
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So, here is a simple solution if you don't care about a perfect parabola. It's all about choosing the suitable coordinates for the controls as well as the end points of the parabolic curve. Drawing a helping grid and removing it in a final run can be useful in this task.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.7pt, scale=.7]
    \draw (2,2)  circle (1cm);
    \draw (2,-3) .. controls (6,1) and (6,3) .. (2,7);
    \draw (10,2) circle (3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{All points that are equidistant from both circles, lie on the hyperbola}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's very good too.

Comment: tikz has a `parabola` action

Answer (score 1):

A solution computing the hyperbola. Not too difficult, and I suppose that the OP knew how to do it. The radii and distance between circles are the same as the initial example. The figure is accurate and customizable but, *caveat emptor*: it's easy to get a `dimension too large` error with little changes.

Below (and in the LaTeX document) I'll add a little explanation about the involved maths.

**The code**

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for the maths part (no needed for the picture)
\usepackage{cancel}    % ditto
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
% parameters
\def\ra{1} % radius, left circle 
\def\rb{3} % radius, right circle
\def\dc{8} % distance between centers
% maths (explained below)
\pgfmathsetmacro\xa{-0.5*(\dc+\ra-\rb)} % placing the circles at the 
\pgfmathsetmacro\xb{ 0.5*(\dc-\ra+\rb)} % same distance form the origin
\pgfmathsetmacro\p{(\xb-\xa)/(\ra-\rb)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\q{(\xa*\xa-\xb*\xb-(\ra-\rb)*(\ra-\rb))/(2*(\ra-\rb))}
\pgfmathsetmacro\k{\p*\q+\xb}
\tikzset{declare function={
   fx(\x)=2*\k*cos(\x)*cos(\x)/(1-\p*\p*cos(\x)*cos(\x));    % hyperbola, x=rho(theta)*cos(theta)
   fy(\x)=2*\k*sin(\x)*cos(\x)/(1-\p*\p*cos(\x)*cos(\x));    % hyperbola, y=rho(theta)*sin(theta)
   dd(\x)=sqrt((fx(\x)-\xa)*(fx(\x)-\xa)+fy(\x)*fy(\x))-\ra; % distance from the hyperbola to A (or B)
}}
% circles
\draw[thick] (\xa,0) coordinate (A) circle (\ra);
\draw[thick] (\xb,0) coordinate (B) circle (\rb);
% hyperbola
\def\d{7} % domain
\draw[red,very thick] plot[domain=90-\d:90+\d] ({fx(\x)},{fy(\x)});
% tangent circles (not in the original picture)
\clip (\xa-2*\ra,{1-fy(90-\d)}) rectangle (\xb+\rb,{-1-fy(90+\d)});
\foreach\i in {-\d,...,\d}
{
  \coordinate        (aux) at (({fx(90+\i))},{fy(90+\i))});
  \draw[gray]        (aux) circle ({dd(90+\i)}) \ifnum\i=\d node[black,above] {$P(x,y)$}\fi;
  \draw[gray,dashed] (A)  -- (aux) -- (B);
  \draw[fill=white]  (aux) circle (0.5mm);
}
\foreach\i in {A,B}
  \draw[fill=white] (\i) circle (0.5mm) node[below] {$\i$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{All points that are equidistant from both circles lie on the hyperbola.}
\end{figure}

% Ignore this if you don't need to know about the maths
\section{The maths}
The circle centers are $A(x_a,0)$, $B(x_b,0)$, and let $P(x,y)$ be a generic point at the hyperbola. Then,
\begin{align*}
d(P,A) & = d(P,B);\\
\sqrt{(x-x_a)^2+y^2}-r_a & =\sqrt{(x-x_b)^2+y^2}-r_b;\\
(x-x_a)^2+\cancel{y^2}   & =(x-x_b)^2+\cancel{y^2}+(r_a-r_b)^2+\\
& \phantom{{}={}}+2(r_a-r_b)\sqrt{(x-x_b)^2+y^2};\\
2(x_b-x_a)x+x_a^2-x_b^2+(r_a-r_b)^2 & =2(r_a-r_b)\sqrt{(x-x_b)^2+y^2};\\
\underbrace{\frac{x_b-x_a}{r_a-r_b}}_p x+\underbrace{\frac{x_a^2-x_b^2+(r_a-r_b)^2}{2(r_a-r_b)}}_q & = \sqrt{(x-x_b)^2+y^2};\\
(px+q)^2 & =(x-x_b)^2+y^2;\\
p^2x^2+2pqx+\cancel{q^2} & = x^2+y^2-2x_bx+\cancel{x_b^2};\\
\intertext{If we take the origin equidistant form both circles, we can cancel the constant terms. Now we change to polar coordinates, $x=\rho\cos\theta$, $y=\rho\sin\theta$.}
p^2\rho^2\cos^2\theta+2pq\rho\cos\theta & =\rho^2-2x_b\rho\cos\theta;\\
p^2\rho\cos^2\theta+2pq\cos\theta & =\rho-2x_b\cos\theta;\\
\rho & =\frac{2\overbrace{(pq+x_b)}^k\cos\theta}{1-p^2\cos^2\theta}=\frac{2k\cos\theta}{1-p^2\cos^2\theta}.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

**The output**

[image]

**And the maths**

The circle centers are A(x_a,0), B(x_b,0), and let P(x,y) be a generic point at the hyperbola. Then,

[image]

If we take the origin equidistant form both circles, we can cancel the constant terms. Now we change to polar coordinates.

[image]